# Is there a way to have loops with multiple conditional criterias to run faster

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have multiple conditions to be met within the loop, I think this is what makes it go slower. Every time I add a new condition it gets even slower. Any suggestions on how to make it run faster? See below for code.

```
Sub A1_GET_DATA()
'Clear Range
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

'Declare Variables
Dim LastRow1 As Integer
Dim LastRow2 As Integer


'Establish Loop
LastRow1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 14 To LastRow1

'Condition for Loop
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    LastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i - 1, 1).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    LastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow2, 20).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow2, 20).Value = "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow2, 20).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    
    

End If
Next
```

Comment: Don't reference the sheets within the loop. Switch to a Variant array (search that term)

Answer (score 0):

- Using `Select` `Active` makes the code slower

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub A1_GET_DATA()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, i As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    'Establish Loop
    LastRow1 = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    With oSht2
        'Clear Range
        .Cells.ClearContents
        For i = 14 To LastRow1
            'Condition for Loop
            If Len(oSht1.Cells(i, 7).Value) > 0 Then
                LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
                oSht1.Rows(i).Copy .Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1)
                LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
                oSht1.Cells(i - 1, 1).Copy .Cells(LastRow2, 20)
                If .Cells(LastRow2, 20).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(LastRow2, 20).Formula2R1C1 = .Cells(LastRow2 - 1, 20).Formula2R1C1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```